# escape javascript doesn't work with link_to_function (rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

This line works fine

```
        <%=link_to_function "name", "$('#thing_name').html('<p>name<p>')" %>
```

This line doesn't

```
        <%=link_to_function "name", "$('#thing_name').html('<%= escape_javascript(thing.name) %>')" %>
```

Then I get rid of all the content within <%= %>

```
       <%=link_to_function "name", "$('#thing_name').html('<%= %>')" %>
```

It still keeps complaining about some weird compile errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already inside an ERB block due to the opening `<%=` at the very beginning, and you cannot use another one. Use [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) to evaluate Ruby code inside the string:

```
<%= link_to_function "name", "$('#thing_name').html('#{escape_javascript(thing.name)}')" %>
```

Alternatively, if for some reason you don't want to use interpolation:

```
<%= link_to_function "name", "$('#thing_name').html('" + escape_javascript(thing.name) + "')" %>
```

Comment: Does the answer above work in rails 3.1.0 or above? I could not make the answer above work on my rails 3.1.0

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought you need to escape out of the string:

```
<%=link_to_function "name", "$('#thing_name').html('"<%= escape_javascript(things.name) %>"')" %>
```

Note the double quotes around `<%= escape_javascript(things.name) %>`

Should work... although im still a little new to erb's :)